# VBA - copying data across multiple sheets

Tags: vba

I'm attempting to copy data from multiple worksheets in cells `M78:078` into one, where the name in the `col L` of the summary sheet matches to the worksheet name (pasting into columns `Z:AA` in the summary sheet.

At present the below code has a Run-time error '13' type mismatch on that line that includes "A1":

Any input / advice would be appreciated

```
Sub Output_data()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsGet As Worksheet
    Dim LCell As Range
    Dim sDataCol As String
    Dim lHeaderRow As Long

    sDataCol = "L"  'Change to be the column you want to match sheet names agains
    lHeaderRow = 1  'Change to be what your actual header row is

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")    'Change this to be your Summary sheet

    'Check for values in sDataCol
    With ws.Range(sDataCol & lHeaderRow + 1, ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, sDataCol).End(xlUp))
        If .Row <= lHeaderRow Then Exit Sub 'No data

        'Loop through sDataCol values
        For Each LCell In .Cells
            'Check if sheet named that value exists
            If Evaluate("ISREF('" & LCell.Text & "'!A1)") Then
                'Found a matching sheet, copy M78:O78 to the corresponding row, column Z and on
                Set wsGet = wb.Sheets(LCell.Text)
                wsGet.Range("N78:R78").Copy ws.Cells(LCell.Row, "Z")
            End If
        Next LCell
    End With

End Sub
```

DRod

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error whenever is see Blank values in the LCell.Text, So Try this.

```
If LCell.Text <> "" Then 
If Evaluate("ISREF(" & LCell.Text & "!A1)") Then
        'Found a matching sheet, copy M78:O78 to the corresponding row, column Z and on
        Set wsGet = wb.Sheets(LCell.Text)
        wsGet.Activate
        wsGet.Range("M78:O78").Copy
        ws.Activate
        ws.Cells(LCell.Row, "Z")
    End If
End if
```

Comment: Any idea how I would activate the worksheet indicated in LCell and copy the data from the range on my summary sheet, into that worksheet?

Comment: I have modified the answer to activate the LCell sheet. What is the other action you are looking at?

Comment: Based on the name in column L, I want to copy the data in the corresponding line from columns N to R, and then paste it into the relevant worksheet (as indicated by the name in column L)

Comment: Sorry im confused. Your Code is Coping Range("M78:O78") from Sheet( i.e.,LCell.Text) and then trying to paste to wb.Sheets("Summary")